# I am confused about a programming problem i was solving on codeforces and i think the problem itself is wrong

Tags: python

This is the question statement

Ivan has a robot which is situated on an infinite grid. Initially the robot is standing in the starting cell (0, 0). The robot can process commands. There are four types of commands it can perform:

```
U — move from the cell (x, y) to (x, y + 1);
D — move from (x, y) to (x, y - 1);
L — move from (x, y) to (x - 1, y);
R — move from (x, y) to (x + 1, y).
```

Ivan entered a sequence of n commands, and the robot processed it. After this sequence the robot ended up in the starting cell (0, 0), but Ivan doubts that the sequence is such that after performing it correctly the robot ends up in the same cell. He thinks that some commands were ignored by robot. To acknowledge whether the robot is severely bugged, he needs to calculate the maximum possible number of commands that were performed correctly. Help Ivan to do the calculations!
Input

The first line contains one number n — the length of sequence of commands entered by Ivan (1 ≤ n ≤ 100).

The second line contains the sequence itself — a string consisting of n characters. Each character can be U, D, L or R.
Output

Print the maximum possible number of commands from the sequence the robot could perform to end up in the starting cell.

Some Test Examples:

Input:

4

LDUR

Output:

4

Input:

5

RRRUU

Output:

0

Input:

6

LLRRRR

Output:

4

And here is the solution i wrote it passes the first 3 test cases by gives wrong output(40) in test case 4
the input of test case 4 is as follows

88
LLUUULRDRRURDDLURRLRDRLLRULRUUDDLLLLRRDDURDURRLDURRLDRRRUULDDLRRRDDRRLUULLURDURUDDDDDLDR

Now i wanted to know that why the correct answer is 76 because at 76th command value of cor!=[0,0] means it didnt even reach the origin.
only at 40th command the cor==[0,0] they both are 0 which is the maximum from 0-88 for the test case.

Here is my program:

```
a = int(input())
ans = input()
cor = [0,0]
arr = [0]
for i in range(a):
    if ans[i]=='L':
        cor[0]-=1
    elif ans[i]=='R':
        cor[0]+=1
    elif ans[i]=='U':
        cor[1]+=1
    elif ans[i]=='D':
        cor[1]-=1
    if cor[0]==0 and cor[1]==0:
        arr.append(i+1)
print(max(arr))
```

Comment: It does not have to be he last commands of the sequence that are not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it.

The robot always ends up at the origin. If the commands would dictate otherwise, then it must be skipping some of them.

We don't need to count through the commands manually, and their order doesn't especially matter - all we need to know is that

- to land back on the origin, the number of 'D' and 'U' commands must be identical
- to land back on the origin, the number of 'L' and 'R' commands must be identical

We can add together all the commands, find the ending coordinates of the robot, and the gridwise distance from origin is how many commands *must* have been skipped. From there, the solution is the total number of commands minus that - the maximum number of commands that may not have been skipped.

```
inp = "LLUUULRDRRURDDLURRLRDRLLRULRUUDDLLLLRRDDURDURRLDURRLDRRRUULDDLRRRDDRRLUULLURDURUDDDDDLDR"
ct_l = inp.count('L')  # 20
ct_u = inp.count('U')  # 18
ct_r = inp.count('R')  # 28
ct_d = inp.count('D')  # 22
num_skipped = abs(ct_l - cd_r) + abs(ct_d - ct_u)  # 8 + 4 = 12
solution = len(inp) - num_skipped)  # 88 - 12 = 76
print(solution)
```

---

In the solution you've presented, your `arr` doesn't especially matter. I believe that, if you walked through the entire string of commands, then `len(a) - abs(cor[0]) + abs(cor[1])` would get you the right answer.

Comment: Yes I figured the a-abs(cor[0])+abs(cor[1]) part already thank you !

Comment: It's actually much simpler: just do `solution = 2 * (min(ct_l, ct_r) + min(ct_u, ct_d)`)